# Encrypting a password for use with SetPasswordText()

Tags: java, encryption, silktest

I am implementing UI tests with Silk4J. To log in I used the `SetText()` method until now. However, using a plain text password in my source code is not such a good idea.

Now I found that there is also [SetPasswordText() [MicroFocus]](http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/topic/com.borland.silktest.silk4net.doc/langref/SAP/SetPasswordTextMethodSapTextField_ref.html#d0e1), which takes an encrypted password as parameter.

**Unfortunately the documentation does not specify a way to convert my plaintext password into an encyrpted password. How can I do that?**

I found [a website mentioning a tool](http://community.microfocus.com/borland/test/silk_testpartner_-_automating_functional_tests/w/wiki/84.how-can-i-encryptdecrypt-a-string-in-a-testpartner-test-script.aspx), but that tool does not exist on my machine. It also mentions an `Encrypt()` method, but for Java, I need at least a class name to access that method.

Comment: Why do you care about encrypting the passwords used in a test? Surely, you're testing on a test system that doesn't use the same passwords as your production system?

Comment: @PhilippReichart: that's true, it is a test system and I don't use the password anywhere else. Still, it seems possible and it's always a good habit to do things right.

Comment: I agree with Philipp. Why is it right to encrypt test passwords?

Comment: @Duncan: if it's wrong to encrypt passwords, why did they implement such a method? If you can explain why it is wrong, maybe I accept that as an answer.

Comment: @ᵺṓᵯᶏᵴ Perhaps I've mistaken you. Are you wanting to convert your application code (also used in production) to use `SetPasswordText` rather than `SetText` or are we purely talking about test code here?

Comment: @Duncan: my code is test code only. Perhaps it is only curiosity why I'm asking the question. Maybe it's also useful for someone else who wants to use it in production code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't any way in the UI to encrypt your password. You have two options:

1. Record entering text into the password field. This will record the text entered using the `setPasswordText()` method, which you can copy and paste into your test.
2. Write a short test that calls `Agent.encrypt()`. This will return the encrypted version of the text passed in. Copy the return value of this method into your original test.